# How to suppress serial warning for a static block where a final static variable is initialized and manipulated?

Tags: java, java-7

I have a

```
public final static java.util.Map<String, Type> VAR;
static {
    VAR = new java.util.HashMap<>();
    VAR.put("a", new com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken<List<Integer>>(){}.getType());
}
```

Where the missing `serialVersionUID` in `TypeToken` (of `guava` 18.0) causes a `[serial]` warning, which I want to suppress because its not useful. I'd like to avoid adding `@SuppressWarnings("serial")` to the class because it's too broad. Neither the static block not the declaration accepts the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation. I can' move the initialization to a static method because other the constant might not have been initialized (compiler error).

I'm using Java 1.7.

Comment: So why is the `serialVersionUID` missing?

Comment: Neither of these pieces of code will produce the warning you are trying to suppress. Your question does not make sense.

Comment: @EJP `com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken` implements `java.io.Serializable` and thus (the compiler) wants a `serialVersionUID` in the empty implementation. I.e. in order to write warning-free code I need to write `new com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken<List<Integer>>(){private final static long serialVersionUID = 0;}.getType()` or suppress the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possibility:

```
  public final static Map<String, Type> VAR;

  private static Type listOfIntegerType()
  {
      @SuppressWarnings("serial")
      TypeToken<List<Integer>> t = new TypeToken<List<Integer>>(){};
      return t.getType();
  }

  static {
      VAR = new HashMap<>();
      VAR.put("a", listOfIntegerType());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a static block:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public final static java.util.List VAR = new java.util.LinkedList() {
   ...
};
```

Comment: Just realized, that my question was badly asked. The issue was another.